# Retrieve an element with Jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to be able to get any element on the page only going by its attached attribute..so for example on a page I have

```
 <div id="divId" name="john" style="background-color: red;">
This is alot of text
</div>
```

I want to get this element and update its background colour...but in any case it might not be a div, with a name it could be a ul and an li...

so for example Iv found an example where I can do:

```
<div>
    <ul data-continent="North America">
        <li data-species="California condor">Critically Endangered</li>
        <li data-species="American bison">Near Threatened</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and if I say

```
alert($( "ul[data-continent='" + 'North America' + "'] li[data-species='" + 'California condor'  +"']").html());
```

this will output 'Critically Endagered'

I want to apply this way of getting an element to my original div...so I have tried

```
 var e1 = $("div[name='" + 'john' + "']" ).html()
     e1.style.backgroundColor = "lightblue";
```

this is returning undefined...I know there are other ways to get elements but I want to learnt this way what am i doing wrong

Thank You

Comment: `html()` returns a string, not a dom element,  so last one definitely won't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off you're unnecessarily concatenating information together. You should be doing something like this:

```
var e1 = $("div[name='john']" ).html()
```

The concatenation is really only needed if you're placing a variable in the selector somewhere, which you're not doing. There's also no need for `.html()` as that would get the HTML content of the div and you just want to change the CSS of the element.

Second, at this point `e1` is a jQuery object, so trying to use plain vanialla JavaScript to access properties will fail when you do:

```
e1.style.backgroundColor
```

You *could* use `.get(0)` or `[0]` to dereference the jQuery object and access the underlying node like:

```
e1[0].style.backgroundColor
```

or

```
e1.get(0).style.backgroundColor
```

but the proper way would to continue to use jQuery methods, like `.css()` in this case:

```
e1.css('backgroundColor', 'lightblue');
```

Example:

```js
var e1 = $("div[name='john']")
//e1.get(0).style.backgroundColor = 'lightblue';
//e1[0].style.backgroundColor = 'lightblue';

e1.css('backgroundColor', 'lightblue');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divId" name="john" style="background-color: red;">
  This is alot of text
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues in your code.

First is that you get the html with `.html()`,  which returns the actual html text and not the element so you cannot style it.

the following would fix it

```
var e1 = $("div[name='" + 'john' + "']" ).get(0);
    e1.style.backgroundColor = "lightblue";
```

Additionally you could use the `.css` jquery method to style the element.

```
var e1 = $("div[name='" + 'john' + "']" );
    e1.css({
             'background-color': "lightblue"
           });
```

Last, if you do not want to limit your self to just `div` elements, just remove the div from the selector

```
var e1 = $("[name='" + 'john' + "']" )
```

and it will select all elements that have `name` attribute with `john` as its value.

Answer (score 0):

It can be pretty simple, select by data attribute using a variable:

```
   var mychoice = "North America";
   var mything =$('*[data-continent="' + mychoice + '"]');
```

Same with any attribute